# Hexomino Puzzle

Tags: tiling

First, draw out a 10x10 grid. Take the shape below and see how many you can fit in the 10x10 grid. It should take up 6 grid squares. Also, it can be rotated.
[image: Hexomino]

**1)** How many can you fit in the grid?

**2)** Can you prove that this is the most possible?

All credit goes to "Math Nite" at the University of Calgary

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1)

> I managed to put 16 shapes into the image [image: Solution]

2)

> This is the maximum possible, as there are only four squares left

Comment: This was the same solution that I had. So far, this is the only one I've seen with 16 (without just rotating it.)

Comment: @Faraz there are only 4 grids squares left, so obsiously it is impossible to include another piece of 6 squares. Even if the shape was other, the maximum number of figures you can fit is 16, as 16*6=96, so you will never be able to include another figure of 6 squares, unless you have 102 blanks spaces instead of 100.

Comment: I probably didn't say that very clearly. What I was trying to say is that I know 16 is the most, but this is the only configuration I've seen for 16 so far. @D.Mellow

Comment: Alright, now do the picture with only 4 colors on the map ;)

Comment: @Faraz I verified using a computer program that the solution is essentially unique. It found only this configuration and its mirror image.

Comment: I guess this is the only possible way to do it then, good job!

Comment: @phroureo There you go

Comment: My program agrees the solution is unique. I searched a bit further, trying to find a larger square with a higher packing density than the current 10x10 with 96% density. No joy so far, busy searching squares 24 through 29 with six copies running at once. Can someone come up with a proof that 96% is maximal to free up some of my CPU cores please...

Comment: This hexomino, like all hexominoes, can tile the plane. However, it cannot tile a rectangle. It follows that the tiling density for an arbitrarily large square can be arbitrarily close to, but not equal to, 100%.

Comment: You're right of course... that means my search should continue. But finding "the smallest square with tiling density higher than 96%" may well be out of range of a computer search. In fact someone with a knack at hand solving might find the answer more easily/quickly.